# get warning when reaching certain database size

Tags: sql-server

We are using MS SQL Express where database is limited to 10 GB. We ran into problems lately where we reached the 10 GB and figured it out by users telling us that the apps are not working anymore.

In MS SQL Server Management Studio we have the option to get

Reports - Standard Reports - Disk Usage

And there we see how many % of the table are at the moment unused.

Is it possible somehow to get a notification when reaching 90% of DB Size = 9GB?

Thanks for the help
Andreas

Comment: Does your Windows support MSG.exe command? Or in what way do you want to receive a notification? Your problem is that you use Express Edition that does not support SQL Server Agent, i.e. Alerts are unavailable to you